# How to turn on Bluetooth without Fn + F2?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I would like to know if there is a way to turn my laptop's bluetooth adapter on, without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> keyboard shortcut?

The reason is, for some reason, it does not work properly. Sometimes I have to double press that shortcut, or triple press. It's just random. I want to be able to click on a button with my mouse to open bluetooth.

Is there anything I can do for this? Device manager? Driver software? Any way without <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>?

Or any way to ensure that <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> will work? (but please not this. I mean, one of the above. a software interface.)

Comment: Thanks for the edits karel. I don't know how to type keys :)

Comment: You can thank me better by trying this. Those stupid keys usually have to be pressed and held down for **exactly** one second (or close to one second). Then they will work as expected every time. I know it's not the asnswer you wanted, but it's easier that way once you learn the trick.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Hope it works :) Thanks again ! And though it is the least wanted answer, it is still a valid one, if you want to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those stupid keys usually have to be pressed and held down for **exactly** one second (or close to one second). Then they will work as expected every time. I know it's not the answer you wanted, but it's easier that way once you learn the trick.

Comment: Thanks for all the help ! I hope it's OK to wait to see if there are other answers. Just for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to remap your keys to another. Try the app called [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

I have used it myself as well, it comes very handy especially when a key is missing or just not working.